# Error inflating layout on old phone

Tags: android, xml

This code runs fine on Nexus 5/Lollipop 5.1, but when I tried running on a crappy LG E615f/ICS 4.0.4, this strange error started happening.

```
05-19 18:34:07.639  13037-13037/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.myclass.adapters.TasksAdapter.getView(TasksAdapter.java:66)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2466)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at com.myclass.adapters.TasksAdapter.getView(TasksAdapter.java:66)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2466)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2296)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1658)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1516)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1429)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11345)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2452)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ripple.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200b
```

Here is the `ImageButton` it is complaining about:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/taskItemDownloadBtn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/listItemIconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/listItemIconSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cloud"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

And the two versions of `ripple.xml` it is not finding:

`drawable/ripple.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="?colorControlHighlight" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

`drawable-v21/ripple.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?colorControlHighlight"/>
```

I tried to:

- Change the component from `ImageButton` to `ImageView` and `Button`
  without success;
- Clean the project;
- Remove the background drawable;
- Clean the project again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was actually the `drawable/ripple.xml`. When I removed it the error occurred in other drawable XML with the same problem.

It seems that older Androids can't interpret attribute reference, such as: `?colorAccent` and `?attr:colorControlHighlight`, inside drawable XMLs, only in layout XMLs. Had to fallback there to direct color reference:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/makara" />
            <!-- `?colorControlHighlight` does not work here -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Thanks for the guy who suggested this and deleted the answer later!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused  by a `ResourcesNotFoundException`

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ripple.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200b
```

try adding the file `ripple.xml` inside the `/drawable` folder.

*- 
if you have already this resource just make a refresh of your project and build again, to ensure your resource ID `#0x7f0200b` is added into the `R.java` file.

**well the problem is that the property:**

```
 android:color="?colorControlHighlight"
```

**was added in API level 21**

Comment: The file is well placed. I already tried to refresh the project.

Comment: ok @OrB, check inside your /bin/R.text file what is the resource with the id #0x7f0200b ?